# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException due to named query not found

Tags: database, jpa

I can adding to data to database but I am not getting data from database . Okey I am writing my problem,my entity class Product and I store the database operations on ProductRepository.java 
Then at my database that;its name jsfjpadb.

productId productName salesPrice
1         Kerem       1235
2         Book        23

I am trying to get the data in the database and I want will show on the ProductOzetSayfasi.xhtml but doesnt come.

```
public class ProductRepository {

    public List<Product> list() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("kerem");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
//      String string = "SELECT product FROM Product as product";
//      Query query = manager.createNamedQuery(string);
        TypedQuery<Product> productQuery = manager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p",Product.class);
        List<Product> productList =productQuery.getResultList();
        manager.close();
        return productList;
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="kerem" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.kerem.inventory.entity.Tablo</class>
        <class>com.kerem.inventory.entity.Product</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsfjpadb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="kerem2112"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

```
package com.kerem.inventory.faces;
import java.util.*;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import com.kerem.inventory.entity.Product;
import com.kerem.inventory.repository.ProductRepository;

@ManagedBean
public class ProductOzetSayfasiBean {

    private List<Product> productList;

    public ProductOzetSayfasiBean() {
        ProductRepository repository = new ProductRepository();
        productList = repository.list();
    }

    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        return productList;
    }

}
```

```
package com.kerem.inventory.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int productId;
    private String productName;
    private double salesPrice;

    public Product() {
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return this.productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public double getSalesPrice() {
        return this.salesPrice;
    }

    public void setSalesPrice(double salesPrice) {
        this.salesPrice = salesPrice;
    }
}
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Product</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Product</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable value="#{productOzetSayfasiBean.productList}" var="product">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{product.productId}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

STACK TRACE

```
INFO: Creating instance of com.kerem.inventory.faces.ProductOzetSayfasiBean
[EL Info]: 2020-05-01 04:44:00.226--ServerSession(985404382)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
Fri May 01 04:44:00 PDT 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri May 01 04:44:01 PDT 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
[EL Info]: connection: 2020-05-01 04:44:02.365--ServerSession(985404382)--file:/D:/EclipseProjeleri/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/kerem/WEB-INF/classes/_kerem login successful
May 01, 2020 4:44:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/kerem] threw exception [NamedQuery of name: select product from Product as product not found.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: select product from Product as product not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1124)
    at com.kerem.inventory.repository.ProductRepository.list(ProductRepository.java:19)
    at com.kerem.inventory.faces.ProductOzetSayfasiBean.<init>(ProductOzetSayfasiBean.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:56)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:333)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:296)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:63)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:123)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:63)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:246)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:2028)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.createDataModel(UIData.java:1976)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1953)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:478)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlTableRendererBase.encodeInnerHtml(HtmlTableRendererBase.java:328)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlTableRendererBase.encodeChildren(HtmlTableRendererBase.java:198)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:549)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:749)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1900)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: please share more details about exception (stacktrace). when are you getting this exception.

Comment: I want open ProductOzetSayfasiPage.xhtml , but it shown <h1>Product </h1> then it is not showing dataTable just Product . and ProductOzetSayfasiPage.xhtml  the under codes I throw.I connect database but dataTable is not showing. And I am getting http 500 error

Comment: I found the stacktraces and if you look i happy.I put above.

Comment: createNamedQuery requires name of query as argument but not the actual query.

Comment: Your error btw does not match the active code but the commented code!

Answer (score 0):

define named query via annotation or in xml mapping file. `createNamedQuery` requires name of query but not the actual query. If you dont want to go that way, use `createQuery` instead. `createQuery` takes actual query.

Refer [Creating Queries using JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html)